# solr balanced indexing

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have two Solr server. The databases every day large amounts of data changes will happen. How I know and automate the problem that, until solr0 adding/commiting/warmuping, while just solr1 serve, and if it is completed, then solr1 adding/commiting/warmuping, and serves the solr0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider replication.  Set solr0 as your master and solr1 as a slave.  Reindex on solr0 and, once it is finished and committed, solr1 will start pulling the new index.  If the reindexing load is so significant that solr0 can't serve queries while it is reindexing, you could use something like varnish in front of the Solr servers and mark solr0 as inactive wile indexing.  All of this can be automated by writing scripts that query the Solr DIH and replication status endpoints.

Comment: The warmup stage is executed in such a way that the most popular searches chassing again. If solr0 graduated the commitand/warmup stage, and replicate to solr1, the fresh cashs stock is be replicated from solr0 to solr1?

Comment: @eMber only the index is replicated, not any of the caches.  If you had a script handling load balancer juggling for the active solr core, you could move cache warming to that script to ensure that traffic doesn't go to any core that isn't warmed after indexing/replication.